# Javascript - Event once an element has a value

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden input, and during the logic I set the value of that hidden input.

Is there a event once this hidden input value is set ?

Given the hidden input added on the fly

Comment: you can try something like `onchange`

Comment: Alternatively there is also the input event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Answer (score 1):

when you set the value of the hidden input can you trigger an change event and then catch that? something like below. As you said "I set the value" I assume you could do that.

```
$('#yourElelentId').change(function(){
 
});

$('#yourElelentId').val(100).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you @A Paul for your reply.  How can I do the same given the input field will be Injected dynamically in the form ?

Comment: you can use the jquery "on" for the change function. the first line. That will get called even if you dynamically add the input at any point of time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Changes the value to hidden elements don't automatically fire the change event.

#### Solution

So you have to tell it jquery to fire it and you can do this with the .change() method.

```js
let input = $("#example");
input.hide();
input.change(function(){
  console.log("Value has changed");
});




input.val(10).change();
input.val(30).change();


$("form").append(`<input type="text" value="${input.val()}">`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="example" placeholder="Type in a value" name="name"/>
<p id="values"></p>


<form>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your reply,  How can I do the same given the input field will be Injected dynamically in the form ?

Comment: in which form@User ?

Comment: I have a form in HTML, and through JS SDK I append hidden input to this form

Comment: so you want append as a new input field to it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to do it @User